# SharePont 2016: How to make "Creator" column UNIQUE

Tags: sharepoint-server, column, enforce-uniquevalue

I want to enforce unique values for "Created by" column. the "Created By" column unique. When I have to add a new element and an item really exist in the same "Created By" list - it shows an error message.

How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Creator? You mean SharePoint default Created By column?

Comment: Yes i want to enforce unique values for "Created by" column.

Comment: Can i do this with calculated column?

Comment: You can create event receiver on item adding and item updating events to check if created by user is unique in list or not.

Comment: Event receiver is one good way. If you are doing it on client side then you can fetch all list items and check if there is already an entry for current user in Created By column and show the error message(But it will affect performance if list items are more).

Comment: Thank you, guys.

Comment: Per my test, there is no OOTB method to achieve it.